# Can Android Native App Install be considered as iOS Smart App Banners?

Tags: android, nativeapplication, smart-app-banner

I see conflicting information regarding Android's 'Native App Install' feature. I still have the following questions. Can someone help to clarify ?

1. Can we say it is Android's equivalent of iOS Smart App Banner ?
2. Does it show if app is installed ?
3. Does it allow to pass any context/data from the link to App (post install & launch). Like the 'app-argument' (in iOS) or 'referrer url' (Android) ?

Comment: Can you link to sources for all of your references?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, though Android requires a bit more work to get it up and running
2. Based on os

   - `iOS`

     - Not installed: it will display `View`, to view on the app store.
     - Installed: it will display `Open`
   - `Android`

     - Not installed: it will display a different banner based on device. Some will click the install prompt and redirect to app store. Some will click install prompt and see a modal, then click install prompt again and redirect to app store.
     - Installed: the banner will not appear.
3. Yes

   - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners
   - for Android, use document.referrer